# Web page viewport offset on screen

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

Is it possible to know exact offset of document viewport relative to screen? I.e. is it possible to know point marked wit cross in the image? The point in the image could have coordinates cca x:30, y:150, since I'm not interested in the 0,0 value, nor scroll values, but values relative to the whole screen. If not in js executed from page, then maybe with puppeteer? Thanks.

[image: Point of interest marked with a cross]

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/screenLeft Your searching engine is in the annual service?

Comment: @Teemu, the `screenLeft` is concerned with outer edge of browser. which wouldn't be much of a problem. But `screenTop` is for the top left corner of browser window, not of viewport.